# Prolog - Max value in recursion

Tags: prolog

Hello I doing a work for school and I'm trying to get the max number that is returning by a recursion.
Let me explain better with examples:

I have this predicate:

```
li(_, []).
li(NAME, [H|T]) :- 
   find(NAME, H, Occur),
   li(NAME, T).

li(NAME) :- 
   findall(T, pri(name(T), _, _, _), Info),
   li(NAME, Info).
```

The predicate in line 2 (find), what it does is, by giving a name and some other information it will return to me a number (Occur). What I'm trying to do is to know what is the highets number (Occur) in the whole recursion.

Bellow I tried to do some comparations but it is not working, it says that Highest is not defined, I know that is becouse it don't have any value associated with it but I have not idea how to do this.

```
li(_, [], 0).
li(NAME, [H|T], Highest) :- 
   find(NAME, H, Occur),
   li(NAME, T, Temp),
   Temp is Occur, 
   Highest < Temp,
   Highest is Temp.

li(NAME) :- 
   findall(T, pri(name(T), _, _, _), Info), 
   li(NAME, Info, Return), 
   write(Return).
```

The goal is to write the number in the end of line 3.
Does anyone know what I can do to fix this? Thank you.

**EDIT**

I gave another try and done this:

```
li(_, [], 0).
li(NAME, [H|T], Highest) :- 
   find(NAME, H, Occur), 
   li(NAME, T, Temp), 
   Temp < Occur, 
   Temp is Occur,
   Highest is Temp.

li(NAME) :- 
   findall(T, pri(name(T), _, _, _), Info), 
   li(NAME, Info, Return), 
   write(Return).
```

It doens't trigger any errors but nothing happens, a false is returned and nothing is printed.

**EDIT2**

Thank to @David Tonhofer, I now can get the highst number. But what I realy want is the name that is associated with that hight number.

```
li(NAME, [H|T], Highest, X) :- 
   find(NAME, H, Occur), 
   li(NAME, T, Temp), 
   Highest is max(Temp,Occur), X = ??.
```

I was going step by step and first trying to get the highest number then get the name, but with the MAX now I don't think I can know that.

At first I thought something like this:

```
li(_, [], 0).
li(NAME, [H|T], Highest, X) :- 
   find(NAME, H, Occur), 
   li(NAME, T, Temp), 
   Temp < Occur, 
   Temp is Occur,
   Highest is Temp, X is NAME.

li(NAME) :- 
   findall(T, pri(name(T), _, _, _), Info), 
   li(NAME, Info, Return, X), 
   write(Return), write(X).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a problem:

```
li(NAME, [H|T], Highest) :- 
   find(NAME, H, Occur), 
   li(NAME, T, Temp), 
   Temp < Occur, 
   Temp is Occur,
   Highest is Temp.
```

This means:

- Make sure that `Temp < Occur`, backtrack to try something else if not.
- Then unify the numeric values `Occur` and `Temp`. As `Temp` already contains some value, this is the same as testing whether `Occur` and `Temp` are the same value, and backtrack to try something else if not.
- Then unify the numeric values `Highest` and `Temp`.

You seem to want `Highest` to take on the value of `max(Occur,Temp)`.

In that case:

```
li(NAME, [H|T], Highest) :- 
   find(NAME, H, Occur), 
   li(NAME, T, Temp), 
   Highest is max(Temp,Occur).
```

This

1. Computes the `max(Temp,Occur)` (works only if the values of `Temp` and `Occur` .are known at that point)
2. Unifies the result with `Highest`. If `Highest` is still a fresh variable, this is similar to assignment. Otherwise, if `Highest` already contains something, it is similar to comparison.

## Addendum

To get the "Name" that is associated with the maximum value obtained, you proceed the same way:

```
li(Name_max, [H|T], Temp_max) :- 
   find(Name_from_Head, H, Temp_from_Head),
   li(Name_from_Tail, T, Temp_from_Tail), 
   % let's just print what we have right now:
   format("From the Head, we get: Name = ~w, Temp = ~w", [Name_from_Head,Temp_from_Head]),
   format("From the Tail, we get: Name = ~w, Temp = ~w", [Name_from_Tail,Temp_from_Tail]),
   % now a little "helper predicate" can be used for clarity
   % we pass it the 4 logical variables containing names and temps
   % and the 2 logical variables that have been given to "li/3"
   % to fill in with the best data:
   select_max(Name_from_Tail, Temp_from_Tail,
              Name_from_Head, Temp_from_Head,
              Name_max, Temp_max),
    % and we are done; just a printing before returning for fun
   format("Our current max: Name = ~w, Temp = ~w", [Name_max,Temp_max]).


% The helper predicate has two clauses for the two 
% mutually exclusive alternatives
% (the "=:=" case is in the first clause, arbitrarily)

select_max(Name_from_Tail, Temp_from_Tail,
           Name_from_Head, Temp_from_Head,
           Name_from_Tail, Temp_from_Tail) :- 
   Temp_from_Tail >= Temp_from_Head.

select_max(Name_from_Tail, Temp_from_Tail,
           Name_from_Head, Temp_from_Head,
           Name_from_Head, Temp_from_Head) :- 
   Temp_from_Tail < Temp_from_Head.
```

For the helper predicate you could also write, perhaps more clearly:

```
select_max(Name_from_Tail, Temp_from_Tail,
           Name_from_Head, Temp_from_Head,
           Name_max, Temp_max) :- 
   Temp_from_Tail >= Temp_from_Head, % Guard
   Name_max = Name_from_Tail,        % Constrain variables to be equal!
   Temp_max = Temp_from_Tail.

select_max(Name_from_Tail, Temp_from_Tail,
           Name_from_Head, Temp_from_Head,
           Name_max, Temp_max) :- 
   Temp_from_Tail < Temp_from_Head,  % Guard
   Name_max = Name_from_Head,        % Constrain variables to be equal!
   Temp_max = Temp_from_Head.
```

Comment: hello, thank you for your replay, is working, didn't know that was possible like this. I tought only by comparing the values. I have the Highest but do you know how I can return the NAME that is associated with that number? I tought when comparing the numbers, when I get a bigger number I would change some variavle to the new name and in the end return it. I know that right know I dont have  a variable. But now using the max I can not see how to know wich NAME is associated. I'll edit the aswer.

Comment: @Rafael Updated! Please do  not forget to mark the question as answered if all is clear,

Comment: Hello, thank you for all your help. Realy nice explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

In SWI-Prolog, library([aggregate](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) is meant to provide an SQL-like solution for your problem:

```erlang
?- L=[a:1, b:2, c:3], aggregate(max(V,N),member(N:V,L),Max).
L = [a:1, b:2, c:3],
Max = max(3, c).
```

Comment: @DavidTonhofer: your answer is so much instructive. I'm not enough fluent in English to explain like you're able to do. My answer could indeed be OT, since it doesn't mention recursion...